# How to check the root directory of a project in a particular point in time (commit)?

Tags: git

Today we have the following root directories for Linux project:

```
arch 
block 
crypto 
drivers 
firmware 
fs 
include 
init 
ipc 
kernel 
lib 
mm 
net 
samples 
scripts 
security 
sound 
tools 
usr 
virt/kvm
```

I want to check the root directories for a particular point in time (commit: 15c03dd4859ab16f9212238f29dd315654aa94f6 date: 2013-09-29 18:02:38-04).

How can I do it?

I tried to look to some git commands, but I could not find out which command I can use to do it. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do that would be either:

```
git show 15c03dd4859ab16f9212238f29dd315654aa94f6^{tree}
```

or:

```
git ls-tree 15c03dd4859ab16f9212238f29dd315654aa94f6
```

The `ls-tree` incantation shows a little more info than what you present, but it shouldn't be too hard to strip out the unwanted stuff with `cut` or `awk`...

No reason to mess with your current branch pointer or create a new branch. Also, you can abbreviate the hash to a unique prefix, and you could also use branch or tag names instead of the hash, or other acceptable syntax, like `master@{10 days ago}` or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do it The easiest is to can reset your current branch to that point in time using the sha:

```
git reset --hard 15c03dd
```

I personally don't like to do that and will usually checkout into a new branch instead:

```
git checkout -b OldRootDirectory 15c03dd
```

The second approach creates a new branch named `OldRootDirectory` and initializes the head of that branch to the point in time of your commit. It also switches you to that branch.

Comment: `git reset --hard` is not a proper solution for this. You could just checkout the commit though (on a detached head): `git checkout 15c03dd`.

Comment: poke is right; you want to use `git checkout`, not `git reset`, here. Also, creating a branch right away is a bit overkill, unless you're sure you want to create new commits from that point of the history; see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051216/why-does-git-detached-head-even-exist/26054564#26054564).